# sybase update based on sequential column

Tags: t-sql, sybase, updates

Can any one of you please help me out with the below condition in sybase update?

Table A

```
ID   COL1   COL1_AMT   COL2   COL2_AMT   COL3   COL3_AMT   COL4   COL4_AMT
 1    10      100.00    16       50.00    17       80.00    21       90.00
```

Table B

```
ID   FIN_AMT
 1        20
```

Whenever COL1 or COL2 or COL3 or COL4 equals value as '17' then the corresponding amount column COL1_AMT or COL2_AMT or COL3_AMT or COL4_AMT value should be picked from Table A and get updated in Table B FIN_AMT clumn

Here COL3 is 17, so COL3_AMT value 80 should be added in Table B FIN_AMT

Expected Result in Table B

```
ID   FIN_AMT
 1       100      (Already 20 is there, so 80 should be added to this)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can't test on SYBASE, and it's been years, so have mercy on the finer details of the syntax ;)
Something like this ought to do it;

```sql
UPDATE TableB  
  SET TableB.FIN_AMT = TableB.FIN_AMT +
    CASE WHEN TableA.COL1 = 17 THEN TableA.COL1_AMT ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN TableA.COL2 = 17 THEN TableA.COL2_AMT ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN TableA.COL3 = 17 THEN TableA.COL3_AMT ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN TableA.COL4 = 17 THEN TableA.COL4_AMT ELSE 0 END
FROM TableB, TableA
WHERE TableB.ID = TableA.ID
```

Comment: Sorry,missed to include this comment.I have upto COL50.So performance issue is also there.:( Tried something in dynamic query.But not working as  expected

Comment: @salavisa If it's separated into 50 columns, I suspect you'll still not find a much faster way than extending this query (with an indexed ID column) anyway. The dynamic query needs to be pretty much the same when generated, since it needs to mention/condition on all the same columns. The only variant I can think of is doing a huge `UNION ALL` and only do the conditions once, but I'm not sure that'll improve performance.